# Is it possible to detect file format and encoding of file using batch files?

Tags: batch-file, file-format

Is it possible to detect file format and encoding of file using batch files? And if a particular file is not of intended format, throw an error?

Comment: you might be able to detect some particular formats, but you have to know in advance which formats you want to detect.

Comment: I would need to know if the file is in Unix format and Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a *nix guy, I'd want to jump for something more powerful than a batch file, such as Python. (or a shell script, but I'm assuming you're using Windows --- you might look into PowerShell, but I've never tried it.)

Unix has a great utility for this sort of thing, it's named `file`. There appears to be a Windows version here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Basically, you run `file [your filename here]` and `file` spits out a blurb about the file. For example:

```
$ file zdoom-2.4.1-src.7z 
zdoom-2.4.1-src.7z: 7-zip archive data, version 0.3
```

It's not always right, and it doesn't mean that if `file` says "this is a JPEG" that the file is actually a JPEG: it could be corrupt, etc.

Also, if I rename the above 7z archive to "foo":

```
$ file foo
foo: 7-zip archive data, version 0.3
```

... `file` will still get it.

Comment: Hi Thanatos, while this is not the exact solution I looked out for, given my OS environment and other factors, I am marking it as answer since this has driven me to look out for other approaches. Will post the powershell script I have sort of arrived at.    Thanks!